# Why is the duty cycle much wider than it should be? PIC32MZ & PWM

Tags: pic, pwm, duty-cycle

I'm working with the PIC32MZ2048EFM100 and XC32.

I'm using some outputs as PWM signal generators.

There are frequencies for which the pwm works fine, but not for others.

For example to get 24.4 kHz, I make the following configurations:

PR2 = 255 (I use timer 2)

TCKPS<2:0> = 011 = 1:8 prescale value

TPB = 1/50 MHz

Duty Cycle = OC1RS = 0x05.

If the period is given by PR2 plus 1, which would be 256, the duty cycle is very small, but when analyzing this signal with an oscilloscope, the duty cycle is very long, greater than 50% of the signal period.

Any suggestion of what's up?

I attach an image of the signal displayed on the oscilloscope and a capture of the registers T2CON, OC1RS , PR2 & OC1CON.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is PR2 an 8 bit register? 256 is greater then 0xff.

Comment: Looks like the duty cycle is stretched by a slow turn-off time. Does the output need a pulldown resistor? Or are you tri-stating an output pin when you meant to set it low? Schematic of that section may help.

Comment: @Aaron PR2 is 32bit register

Comment: @BrianDrummond A pulldown resistor is not needed. For example for 12 kHz, it works OK. The output is driven by CMOS transistor.

Comment: @BrianDrummond is probably right, the pin is driven high but not low. You don't see at 12khz because of the drop speed. Check your PWM and pin configuration to make sure they are driven correctly. PIC has lots of configuration for pin drive.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for write.

We have discovered the problem.

We verified that in the hardware that was prototype that works without problems, after careful review, it was discovered that the problem was the optocoupler that drives the CMOS transistor.

Although it is high frequency, it doesn't work as indicated by the manufacturer.

It seems that we received a batch with some problem, but it seems that it is a counterfeit of the original chip, since we did not buy them from a recognized supplier.